# How to derive Chernoff Bounds for Sample Variance?

Tags: probability, bounds, multiarmed-bandit

I was reading a paper on Bandits where I encountered this:
[image]

After searching around on the internet I found and understood the first set of bounds quite well. However, I could not find any explanation for the second set of bounds. Can someone derive/explain second set of bounds. Additionally, I know if it is a $\sigma^2-$ Sub-Gaussian then $a$ in the first set of bounds is $\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$. What is it in the second set of bounds?

Comment: Can you please add a reference to the original paper ?

Comment: @Kumar https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05257